# i have program do resequance of words in a way that game can read, but it do not make it in correct sequance idk why

Tags: python, tkinter, logic

Guys im making program help to translate visual novel game to arabic, to add arabic support i edit game font file and i made it show some kanjis (in shift jis) as arabic latters
i enter text in arabic in program and it convert them so special code from kanjis and latin so game can read it and show it as arabic, game have limt, every line should not exeed 27 latter.
[program ver1.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ga7o.png)
showing in game like this
[it can have one more word in first line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXIWu.jpg) 
, program is working fine, but not complatly correct, now in my code each line excluding spaces should have 27 (i make it 26) character as possble, and if adding another word   will exeed 26 latter so the program will make this word in next line, and this line will be shorter that 26.
its ok because i cant make it exeed 27 limt.

and problem here, its wokring fine but calculation way are wrong? some times program can add short word but it do not, then make this word in next line, some times it doing it correctly?
why?
example in the photo, you can calculate and see that first line is 22 latter, next word is 3 latters only so it should be added, but that dont happen. same thing in next line its only 18 and next word is 7 latters so its 25 still less! than 26
this the code resposble for this funcitonalty

```
def adjust_lines(text):
    lines = text.split('\n')
    adjusted_lines = []
    for i in range(len(lines) - 1):
        line = lines[i]
        next_line = lines[i + 1]
        while len(line.replace(' ', '')) < 26 and next_line:
            words = next_line.split(' ')
            last_word = words[-1]
            # Check if adding the next word keeps the line length under 26
            if len(line.replace(' ', '') + last_word.replace(' ', '')) <= 26:
                line = last_word + ' ' + line
                next_line = ' '.join(words[:-1])
            else:
                break
        adjusted_lines.append(line)
        lines[i + 1] = next_line
    adjusted_lines.append(lines[-1])
    return '\\n'.join(adjusted_lines)
```

i tried to make it calculate spaces but didnt work,
i tried to make it dont calculate \n, but it didnt work
i tried to ask chatgpt and copilot but they cloudnt help?
so i really dont know why this problem happen can you help me please?

Comment: this link of progect in git-hub
https://github.com/abdalgani1/Auto-AR-Visual-Novel/releases/tag/v1.5.0

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you could include example input/output/expected outputs - [ask]

Comment: my qus had example but lets write another one
input:
والان وكأنه يحاول التغطية على ذلك الضجيج، كثافة الثلج المتناثر من السماء تزداد
output now:
或葵卯 い稲鯵羽鮎阿 淫@暗尉ぁ 印斡移圧@ 員意@\n茜葵挨阿 い吋暗挨圧 n茜稲夷欝阿 胤庵叡\n穐i穐荏哀 m暗芦宛阿 咽因 絢杏暗愛鮎芦阿
you can see from first of text until first \n there is 22 latter only, line can handle until 26 so we can add one more word and like this output i want it is:
胤庵叡 或葵卯 い稲鯵羽鮎阿 淫@暗尉ぁ 印斡移圧@ 員意@\n絢杏暗愛鮎芦阿 茜葵挨阿 い吋暗挨圧 n茜稲夷欝阿 \n穐i穐荏哀 m暗芦宛阿 咽因 絢杏暗愛鮎芦阿

Comment: There is a [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module. Does it meet your needs?